# Button click only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button which appends a new input element to the end of the "forPassengers" div once it's clicked, but it only works once. After one click it's not clickable anymore.

**Controller:**

```
app
.controller('multipleFlightsController', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.addPassenger = function () {
        document.getElementById('forPassengers')
            .innerHTML += '<input class="form-control airport ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="text" ng-model="additionalPassengers" placeholder="#" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"> ';
    };
 /*..... more code*/
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="forPassengers" class="col-lg-2 form-group">
    <label># of other passengers</label>
    <button id="buttonForPassenger" type="button" class="btnBlue" ng-click="addPassenger()">Add passenger</button>
    <input class="form-control airport" type="text" ng-model="additionalPassengers" placeholder="#">
    <input class="form-control airport" type="text" ng-model="additionalPassengers" placeholder="#">
 </div>
```

### **WORKING SOLUTION (edit)**

Eventually what solved my problem was actually using AngularJS instead of accessing the input element through the document.getElementById function.

Comment: The controller may not be assigned in the `div`.

Comment: where is the element with id forPassengers

Comment: @HappyCoding How do I check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your $scope:

```
$scope.passengers = [];
$scope.addPassenger = function () {
    $scope.passengers.push({});
};
```

and then with ng-repeat:

```
<!-- use ng-repeat... -->
<input ng-repeat="passenger in passengers" class="form-control airport ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="text" ng-model="additionalPassengers" placeholder="#" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false">
```

Answer (score 1):

Reason why it works once is that angularJS does quite a bit of magic under the hood. And by overriding the innerHTML of the object you wipe the angular's bindings from the child nodes.

use ng-repeat as was suggested.

```
 $scope.people = [];
 $scope.addPassenger = function () {
   // document.getElementById('forPassengers').innerHTML += '<input class="form-control airport ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="text" ng-model="additionalPassengers" placeholder="#" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"> ';
   $scope.people.push({name:"person" + counter});

   counter= counter + 1;
};


<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div id="forPassengers" class="col-lg-2 form-group">
<label># of other passengers</label>
<button id="buttonForPassenger" type="button" class="btnBlue" ng-click="addPassenger()">Add passenger</button>
<input class="form-control airport" type="text" ng-model="additionalPassengers" placeholder="#">
<input class="form-control airport" type="text" ng-model="additionalPassengers" placeholder="#">
<input ng-repeat="person in people" class="form-control airport ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="text" placeholder="#" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" ng-model="person.name">
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/nkigg8j7NBDmEdeLeU4t

Angular has a very nice set of  tools to control your view composition together with templates:
ng-repeat
ng-show
ng-hide
ng-if

Try to avoid fixing DOM yourself.